# Passing mouse coords of a div in a JSP to Java

Tags: javascript, jsp

I`m looking for a way to get the x,y coords of where I clicked in my WebApp using Java EE only. But this seems to be impossible(correct me if I`m wrong).

So I`ve tried to use JS to pass the variables. I know I can use either forms or ajax, but those seem to be limited to one direction, so that I can only send values from Java--->JSP and not the other way around. It seems I can only send strings from JSP--->Java.

Is there a way to - instead of the alert - send thos values directly to a servlet, in the following fiddle?

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) 
 {
    $('#A').click(function(e) {
        alert(e.pageX+ ' , ' + e.pageY);
    });    
});
```

```css
#A 
{ 
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  cursor:pointer;
  background:#2f2f2f;
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  color:#fff;
  font:bold 15px Arial; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
 <title> Mouse Positions !! </title>
</head>
    
<body>
    <div id="A" style="left:100px;"> Default    
      <br /> mouse <br/> position 
    </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You could just use simple query params in a URL which would send HTTP GET request.

Comment: Could you give an example please? Since im not familiar with jquery.

Comment: Just create an image. `new Image().src("http://server.url/mouse?x=x&y=y")`

Comment: I`m a little confused...where would I put that line? How does it adress my servlet?

Comment: If you ask those questions, I think you need to understand HTTP a little better

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I used a form to send an request. It's possible to modify the forms value via JS, also its possible to submit via JS. Just find the form by id and change the value.